# UiView fixed on top of UiTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

I need to put an UIView fixed on top of UITableViewController (like a header). I've tried this:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll (scrollView: UIScrollView)  {
     var fixedFrame: CGRect = self.uiTopView.frame;
     fixedFrame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
     self.uiTopView.frame = fixedFrame;
}
```

But it does not work and I don't know why. Someone have any idea?

Comment: As a test, add 66 to `y` value. Does that help?

Comment: Did you add your `tableViewController` through `storyboard`? If so then you can add a `UIView` at the top of your `tableView`.

Comment: rmaddy, thank you for reply. It caused no effect.

Comment: Santosh, thank you for reply. Yes, I, did it. The problem is the UIView at the top of table view is not fixed. If I scroll screen the UIView on top scrolls too. I don't want that

Comment: Does your table contain multiple sections or just 1 number of section?

Comment: Mr. BU, my table has multiple lines, if that's what you're asking. And each line has multiples elements.

Comment: what does your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` returns?

Comment: I tested here and this function returned me 1

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done, one way to accomplish this is to add the UITableViewController inside`UIContainerView`
So the structure will be as follows:

ViewController1 contains a`UIContainerView` this container view has embedded segue 
to your tableViewController.

Then you can add the view to the ViewController1.

Comment: Seriously!? This is so frustrating. Anyway, thank you very much for your reply. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you actually use UITableViewController instead of UIViewController with a tableView inside?

Maybe you should add your header view first then add you tableview depending on the header's frame.

for example: `import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    var fixedLabel : UILabel!
    var tableView : UITableView!

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
     self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.fixedLabel.frame.maxY, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height-70)
     self.fixedLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.width,70)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.fixedLabel = UILabel()
    self.fixedLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.fixedLabel.text = "This is a fixedLabel"
    self.fixedLabel.textAlignment = .Center

    self.tableView = UITableView()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    self.view.addSubview(fixedLabel)
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)

}

 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


   var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell?.textLabel?.text = "Your text"
    return cell!
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}
```

}
`

Comment: Thank you Mat Grlt. Indeed, there's a reason to usage of the UiTableViewController in my case. I am looking for some solution which does not changes too much the code. But, I think this is not possible. Anyway, thank you very much for your reply.